# Lightning Web Components/LWC (no aura): How do you set the maximum length of list when rendering with iterator?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, loop

How do you set the maximum length of a list with LWC? I understand in Angular you could use "ng-maxLength".

```
<template iterator:item={records}>
  <!-- List up to ten records -->
  <c-item-card key={item.value.Id} item={item.value}></c-item-card>
</template>
```

There's also item.index but that still isn't helpful if I cannot pass the index into a handler/expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In LWC, such directives don't exist. You will need to create a separate variable to hold the the shortened list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now, I'm fetching the list via fetch request. I wanted to expand the list with a "Load more" button. So, you're saying I can't short the list on the iterator itself?

Comment: @TheWebDev Yeah. I have to figure out why this is broken, but you can see the source for an example [pagination](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/88mc3Gx8E4OZNksS14kZ/src/app.js?p=stories) table.